ClassNotFoundException: ...PreFlightRequestHandler with Spring Boot 3.4.0 and Spring Cloud 2024.0.0
I am upgrading my project to use Spring Boot 3.4.0 and Spring Cloud 2024.0.0. My pom.xml configuration is as follows:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2024.0.0</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other dependencies -->
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2024.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

After upgrading, I am encountering the following error at runtime:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.cors.PreFlightRequestHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 49 common frames omitted

Does anyone know why this error occurs or if the class org.springframework.web.cors.PreFlightRequestHandler has been removed or replaced in these versions? How can I resolve this issue?
Thank you for your help!
I have tried the following steps without success:

Ensuring that the parent POM and dependencies are compatible with Spring Boot 3.4.0 and Spring Cloud 2024.0.0.
Specifying the exact version of Spring Boot (3.4.0) in the parent section.
Running mvn dependency:tree to check for conflicting dependencies but found nothing unusual.
Confirming that my project is using Java 21, as required by these Spring versions.


the full pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2024.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>2024.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.2.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <!-- TEST -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                        ${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties
                    </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                    <commitIdGenerationMode>full</commitIdGenerationMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>

the full stacktrace
2024-12-19 11:19:18,003 INFO  32647  [      main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication              : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2024-12-19 11:19:18,271 WARN  32647  [      main] o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext      : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.defaultViewResolver
2024-12-19 11:19:18,276 INFO  32647  [      main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger: 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-12-19 11:19:18,286 ERROR 32647  [      main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication              : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.defaultViewResolver
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:99)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:430)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:791)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350)
    at it.konvergence.kss.monitoring.KssHttpProxyApplication.main(KssHttpProxyApplication.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@76ed5528]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:374)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:374)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:750)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:683)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1683)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanDefinitionsForType(OnBeanCondition.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanDefinitionsForType(OnBeanCondition.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanDefinitionsForType(OnBeanCondition.java:293)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:219)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.evaluateConditionalOnMissingBean(OnBeanCondition.java:196)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/cors/PreFlightRequestHandler
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2676)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.cors.PreFlightRequestHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52653', transport: 'socket'



Have you tried using the spring-boot-starter-parent instead of the spring cloud one? This seems weird as you are using both the parent and one in the dependencies management section.

I apologie but i no have understand becose i have to try use spring-boot-starter-parent.
My goal is use spring cloud, if I change the parent and everything works I still haven't achieved my goal.
In any case, if i change version and go back to: <version>2023.0.4</version>
everything works perfectly.
It's frustrating not being able to do the advancement

You are using Spring Cloud through the dependencyManagement section already you don't need the parent. Either you use the parent and no dependencymanagement for Spring Cloud, or don't use the parent and use dependencymanagement but not both at the same time.

I also doubt that all your dependencies are compatible (and that what you posted is your full pom). There are dependencies in there that are pulling in incmopatible versions of SPring (prior to spring framework 6.2 as that is when that interface has been added). So as requested before please add your full pom.xml
